# How can i easily set a jTable's cell to accept floats or decimal

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've created a simple inventory system using netbeans and MS access as my database.

I'm having a problem setting my jtable's  Unit_cost and Total_Cost columns to accept and show decimals that have two decimal places.

I can save my "prices" in my database with its correct amount(i.e. 1999.99) but when i load the data onto the jtable it automatically rounds off my number and omits the decimal point (1999.99 -> 2000).

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code block which does this... It would be much easier to debug then...

Comment: Your table model should override the `getColumnClass` method a return back `Double.class` (or similar).  If you want more control, you could provide a custom cell editor/renderer. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Also, verify the value you are getting from the database is correct before you add it to the UI